# Find n largest values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working in Python project and I have a problem seem as what I explain below but with other data.
For example, if I have this dict:

```
fruitsCount= {"apple": 24, "orange": 20, "banana":18, "grape":13, "kiwi": 13}
```

how can I return the keys with maximum values ? what if I want to return three largest ?

I used `heapq.nlargest(3, fruitCount.values)` but I don't know how I return them with their keys

Note: `fruitsCount` is a dict returned after using `Counter()` from another dict.

Output: should be same `fruitsCount` dictionary with **n largest** `fruitsCount.values`

Comment: What is `nlargest()`? Is that `heapq.nlargest()` perhaps?

Comment: yes heapq.nlargest()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `heapq.nlargest()` on the *items*, and use the `key` argument to tell it to take the value from that pair:

```
heapq.nlargest(3, fruitCount.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

This returns the 3 largest `(key, value)` pairs.

Or you could just use the `collections.Counter()` class, which has a `most_common()` method that does this for you:

```
Counter(fruitCount).most_common(3)
```

Comment: You might want to wrap the above suggestions with a call to `dict()` to produce the requested dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Having never used the `heapq` module, I prefer this module-free approach:

`sorted( fruitsCount.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True )[:3]`

Smaller, but less clear:

`sorted( fruitsCount.items(), key=lambda pair: -pair[1] )[:3]`

Comment: I meant nlargest() from heapq in my question

Comment: The point of the `heapq` module is that it is a more efficient algorithm for picking the N largest items where N < the total number of items.

Comment: I don't think the downvote was necessary.  It is perfectly fair to say that I want to solve the problem without recourse to library routines.  Within that constraint, the answer provided is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. Your answer will be apple, orange, banana.

```
heapq.nlargest(3, d, key=fruitsCount.get)
```

Time complexity in this approach will be `nlog(t)`. N is the number of elements in the dictionary and t is the number of elements you want. In the above case, t is 3.

Answer (score 0):

New to python not very sure about the shortcut, but here is my answer:

```
from heapq import nlargest

fruitsCount= {"apple": 24, "orange": 20, "banana":18, "grape":13, "kiwi": 13}
```

Reverse the key value pairs so that sorting is done wrt values:

```
fruitsCount = {j:i for i,j in fruitsCount.items()}
```

Find the largest 3 items in a separate dictionary:

```
x = dict(nlargest(3,fruitsCount.items()))
```

Reverse the dictionary back to original form:

```
x = {z:y for y,z in x.items()}
print(x)
```