# What would be a quick and effective way to get top 3 highest values from a large dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I've been trying for several hours to go through a dictionary and get three highest-value keys to be presented in the output.

So here's an example dictionary:

```
dict1 = {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 20,
    "d": 15,
    "e": 100,
    "f": 75
}
```

And I want to parse out the three highest values and present them something like this:

```
'e' has a value of 100
'f' has a value of 75
'c' has a value of 20
```

So it should be key-value pairs, not just the values.

I tried something like this but it didn't seem convenient at all.

```
v = list(dict1.values())
k = list(dict1.keys())

print(f"{k[v.index(max(v))]} has a value of {max(v)}.")

# and so forth. not to mention this is only the one highest value, I need three
```

I'm sure there's a really simple way right under my nose. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find n largest values from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548953/find-n-largest-values-from-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

The standard library `Counter` class can make short work of what you are trying to do:

```
from collections import Counter

dict1 = {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 20,
    "d": 15,
    "e": 100,
    "f": 75
}

for k, v in Counter(dict1).most_common(3):
    print(f"{k} has a value of {v}")
```

Output:

```
e has a value of 100
f has a value of 75
c has a value of 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort the dictionary items and print first 3 items:

```py
dict1 = {"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 20, "d": 15, "e": 100, "f": 75}

for k, v in sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[:3]:
    print(f"'{k}' has a value of {v}")
```

Prints:

```
'e' has a value of 100
'f' has a value of 75
'c' has a value of 20
```